# Hibernate validator for ComboBox

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, hibernate-validator

How to validate a jComboBox for user to select any item other than the default item?

I need to check whether the user didn't select any item. So the jComboBox value will be "Please select a scurity question"

[image]

In my model class,

```
@NotEmpty(message="Please fill the username field!")
public String getUsername() {
    return this.username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

@NotEmpty(message="Please fill the password field!")
public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getSeqQue() {
    return this.seqQue;
}

public void setSeqQue(String seqQue) {
    this.seqQue = seqQue;
}
```

What will be the hibernate validator annotation to add in getSeqQue() to validate my jComboBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To validate your JComboBox with custom message simply you can make custom constraint validator.

See following example:

**MyModel.java**

```
public class MyModel {

    @ValidComboBox //this is the annotation which validates your combo box
    private String question;

    //getter and setter
}
```

**ValidComboBox.java** //annotation

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;
import javax.validation.*;

@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ComboBoxValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface ValidComboBox {
String value = "Please select a security question";

String message() default "Please select a security question.";

Class<?>[]groups() default {};

Class<? extends Payload>[]payload() default {};
}
```

**ComboBoxValidator.java**

```
import javax.validation.*;
public class ComboBoxValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidComboBox, String> {

private String value;

@Override
public void initialize(ValidComboBox arg0) {
    this.value = arg0.value;

}

@Override
public boolean isValid(String question, ConstraintValidatorContext arg1) {
    if(question.equalsIgnoreCase(value)){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Add items to your jComboBox like this:

```
JComboBox<String> jComboBox = new JComboBox<>();
jComboBox.addItem("Please select a scurity question");
jComboBox.addItem("Question 1");
jComboBox.addItem("Question 2");
```

And following lines you need to add when you perform action to validate:

```
ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();

String question = jComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
MyModel model = new MyModel();
model.setQuestion(model);

Set<ConstraintViolation<MyModel>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(model);

if (!constraintViolations.isEmpty()) {
        String error = "";
        for (ConstraintViolation<MyModel> constraintViolation : constraintViolations) {
                error += constraintViolation.getMessage();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, error);
        }
}
```

> It will display **Please select a security question** message if you try to send request without choosing question.